# Would it be possible to make a chili that drew its influence from eastern cooking and used curry as a base?

Tags: curry, chili

My plan is to follow the concept of a conventional chili, but replace the chili powder with a homemade curry powder spice blend containing coriander, cumin, turmeric, ginger, peony, lovage, star anise, fennel seeds, Rehmannia, and cayenne. The idea is to sautee the beef with onions and fennel, seasoning it lightly, and then, add it to a beef stock, along with a few varieties of bean, stewed tomato, the curry powder from before, and rice wine. I also had the idea of making miniature naan-parmesan wraps that would be stirred into the chili in the last few minutes of cooking, as to absorb some of the liquid from the chili, in place of the traditional cracker. So my question is, would this work in a way that remained as pleasing to the senses as conventional chili or curry (if not more), and if not, how could I tweak it to make the tastes blend better for a more appealing dish?

Also, how can I add the naan wraps to the chili while having it retain its fluffiness and not getting soggy?

Thank you so much, and I greatly look forward to your response.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Whether it's any good ("pleasing to the senses") is off topic, as it's entirely a matter of opinion. I might think it's great while a Texas might think it's the worst chili ever... The other reading of the first part of your question is a "recipe request" which is also off topic.  The part of this question that is on topic is how you can add naan to a chili/curry without them getting mushy. I'd suggest using the Edit button to focus your question on the naan question, and/or tighten up focus on *specific* concerns with the recipe itself

Comment: I think if we consider it more "is my mad idea going to work?" then we can answer it, 'yes, so long as you don't put the bread in it. Make it a bit thicker first.'

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like a curry with beans, not a chilli with curry powder.
Apart from splashing in soggy nan at the end, which I don't think is going to work, it sounds like it would make a decent aromatic curry.

You don't mention quantities, but I'd go heavy on the onion & hold the stock back to give the end result a 'firmer' gravy, which would mean you have less mopping up to do. I'd also be tempted to get your spice blend in with or even before the onions to enhance the flavours. Maybe add a touch more towards the end to re-lift the aromatics, which will have sunk in a bit over a few hours' cook.

Serve in soup-plates [flat dishes] and use the nan to pick up the curry, rather than attempt to sit the whole thing on a rice bed. If your curry base is firm enough, you could lay out the nans/mini-wraps on the edge of the plate right at service, without giving them time to go soggy.